# How can I detect a collision of a new circle with another circle already created in a for-loop?

Tags: java, android, collision, geometry

i am creating 25 circles in my constuctor and want to have a collision detection within this circle-creation part, so that no circle collides. The collision detection is already working but I don't get it into my circle-creation part.

This is the constructor where I want to create the 25 circles:

```
public Drawing(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.ctx = context;

        viking = new Circle(160,160, 33, "viking", "green", false);

        for(int k = 0; k < circles.length; k++) {
            int randomX = r.nextInt(500);
            int randomY = r.nextInt(750);
            circles[k] = new Circle(randomX, randomY, 33, "Circle"+k, "blue", false);
            circles[k].setX(randomX);
            circles[k].setY(randomY);
            setDrawColor(circles[k]);
            //Collision Detection
             for(int z = 0; z<k;z++) {
                 if(detectCollision(circles[k], circles[z]) == true)
                 {
                     break;
                 }
             }
        }

        pMe.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        p1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        p2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        p3.setColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

The collision detection looks like the following:

```
    public static boolean detectCollision(Circle c1, Circle circleOpponent) {
        dx = circleOpponent.getX() - c1.getX();
        dy = circleOpponent.getY() - c1.getY();
        radiusSum = circleOpponent.getR() + c1.getR();
        return dx * dx + dy * dy <= radiusSum * radiusSum; // true if collision
    }
```

The values in "new Circle" are x- and y-position, radius, name, color and an isDrawn value.

Does anyone know what i have to correct or adjust in for-loop(s)?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in the case that a collision is detected, you want to ignore the newly created circle and go on with creating circles until you have reached 25 circles. Thus your outermost loop should be a while loop. Also you should only add the circle to the array when you have found that it does not collide with any existing circles. Thus introduce a candidate variable. Use the continue statement to go to the next iteration of the outer loop.

```
int createdCircles = 0;
outer: while (createdCircles < 25) {
    Circle candidate = new Circle(...);
    inner: for (int z = 0; ...) {
        if (detectCollision(...)) continue outer;
    }
    circles[createdCircles] = candidate;
    createdCircles++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)! This is working :)! have a nice evening as I will have now :).